# How to hide Backoffice navigation-node based on user group in?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am working with Hybris backoffice and I am trying to hide specific navigation nodes based on user groups. So I have tried to define a **merge-by** attribute
in the context tag along with **principal** group as shown below.

```
<context component="explorer-tree" merge-by="principal" principal="myRestrictedGroup">
    <!-- other nodes... -->
    <navigation-node id="Restricted" merge-mode="remove"/>
</context>
```

I have also created a user who is assigned to the restricted group (myRestrictedGroup).

But when logging in as the restricted user or any other user the node is hidden. For any group/user the node is not visible including "admin". I was expecting the node to be visible to all users that do not belong to the "myRestrictedGroup" but this does not seem to be the case.

I am running Hybris 6.6.

I was following documentation I found online as it seemed to be what I was looking for. However, I did notice the documentation lists few older versions of 6.0. ( I did not see 6.6)
https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/preview/en/2455449   (SAP credentials are needed to view entirely)

Answer (score 1):

There is actually on additional layer of abstraction between standard hybris user groups and backoffice, it's called the [Authority Group](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8b6f8af58669101495a7aa8620585384.html)

So, what it may boil down to for your example to work:

1. create a new "Backoffice Role" (subtype of User group)
2. set the `Authorities` (the property is found in the Administration tab) of this role to `myRestrictedGroup`
3. Assign the role to the users to hide the navigation node